# Choosing service name for Oracle Database connections with cx_Oracle

Tags: python, pandas

I have several database connections within my SQLDeveloper, all using localhost. Now, being new to both SQL and Python, I want to be able to choose with Python which one to connect to.

For Example:

- Database 1 - SchoolInformation {PersonalInfo, Reports etc} as Default Database
- Database 2 - SalesInformation {Consumer, ProductionSales, Reports etc}

If I want to use Database 2 instead of 1 in Python what will I do?

```py
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

con = cx_Oracle.connection('system/oracle@localhost:1521/ex') 
#Can't I be specific here with the Database I want to connect to e.g StudentInfomation or SalesInformation.

cur = con.cursor()
table_info = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Reports").fetchall() #By default this will be executed
df = pd.DataFrame(table_info)
print(df.head(10))
```

Comment: what you put after the slash in the address is the name of the database which will connect.